# How to extract data from a table in a PDF file?

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, text

I have a PDF file containing a table, the format is like this:

[image: pdf img]

Now;I need to extract the data from specific columns from each row to insert in a database.
How can I extract the columns I want only with either javascript or python?

I already tried the manual way but that is not sufficient.

I expect to get the raw data put in a variable (array or list).

==========================================
UPDATE:

I decided to go with python, the library's name is tabula; I installed it using pip:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

You pass the pdf to the library and specify the page of the table. The output of the table in my question looks magically like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I used [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) to extract the items in a pdf, and apply some rules to identify the table elements. The extracted items not only has the text information, but only has an attribute called "transform" (transformation matrix) that contains coordinates information, which can be also used to identify the table elements.

The first thing is to find the beginning of a table. In many cases the headers are the same so you can utilize those words to find a beginning. The first table element in a row may share the same coordinate which can also gives a clue where a table starts. After the beginning of a table is identified, because all the tables are fixed width, the items can be divided to certain columns. Just pay attention that there may be more than one row in a single cell, so that you'll need to combine them.

Comment: please contextualize more your answer, show a code example etc

Comment: I would say the code example is too trivial and meaningless to other people. It is basically a brute force approach to setup the rules after one extract the info of individual items of a PDF. But I'll try to add more description in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try AWS Textract. It has a feature where it extracts tables gives you the data as a csv/json.

you can look up more about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/automatically-extract-text-and-structured-data-from-documents-with-amazon-textract/)

Comment: Isn't there a way to parse the pdf using a python or javascript library ? the amazon AWS T requires credit card

Comment: there is in fact textract library available for python. Link: https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ It's not the same thing though. You could try it out. If you need more accuracy and features and its a business use case, then aws is not a bad option.